# php include path issues in directory

Tags: php, mysqli

Happy new year everyone... I have been working on a project and my file structure is

index.php

functions

profile

includes

main forlder is "mysite"

I have a header and footer if I include into the index.php its fine if I include in profile/index.php I get and error

I have tried to use

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```

but have had not success still errors

the error I get when trying to go to profile/index.php

> Warning: include(C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\profile\index.php on line 2

if you look at the top warning its trying to include from htdocs however the site main folder is mysite

Comment: your header.php is in the "include" and "profile" is a folder right?

Comment: correct my includes folder has header and nav and footer.php my profile folder has index and edit.php plus I have a admin folder that has pages also in which I need to include the header and footer

Comment: Have you tried [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: and you tried `include('../includes/header.php')` ? for /profile/index.php?

Comment: I have not tried getcwd() how would I use that in a include I'm new to php???

Comment: I have tried include('../includes/header.php') but if the header is included in another file in a different directory then I run into issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main folder is mysite, so add mysite after `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for profile/index.php the code will be like this:

`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mysite/includes/header.php');`